# What is the project(s) that branched asp.mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, open-source

I remember reading a blog post about a group that had taken a branch of asp.mvc.

They intend to use it as a base and fix a number of issues while adding features.

Now I can’t seem to work out the magical combination of google keywords to find it.

Does anyone know what this project is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fubu MVC](http://code.google.com/p/fubumvc/) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

All good except the fact that Fubu is not a branch or port of ASP.NET MVC, it's a completely independent framework born out of frustration its authors had when using ASP.NET MVC. It is heavily influenced by ASP.NET MVC in some parts but that's it.